# Problems importing the android support library with resources

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

As soon as I finish importing the android support library project into my workspace (I am using eclipse ide), I receive this error message:

Could not not write to file: C:\Program Files\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\bin

The library project appears in my workspace, however if i try a clean build:

> Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Android
>   Package Builder' on project 'android-support-v7-appcompat'. Resource
>   '/android-support-v7-appcompat/bin' does not exist.

Here is the stack trace:

> [2013-12-17 18:11:20 - android-support-v7-appcompat] Android requires
>   compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use
>   Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

The error log also states that bin folder does not exist/cannot be written to.

Here are things I have tried so far and failed:
1. Clean build
2. Install then re install
3. Fix android properties.

I have not used any of the API from the support library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the project properties in Eclipse. Choose Java Compiler and make sure the Compiler Compliance level is set to 1.5 or 1.6.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have changed the compliance level to 1.5 and 1.6. I recieve the following messages from the error log on level 1.5:                                                                              Error: Exception occurred while saving project preferences: /android-support-v7-appcompat/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs.         It also cannot write to the settings folder in appcompat\.settings

Comment: Running eclipse in administrator mode solved this issue.